# Tr of matrix in Kullback-Leibler divergence PRML2.13

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I've learned PRML recently but get stuck in a math problem.
this exercise is to calculate $KL$ divergience of $2$ multi Gaussian
$$  N(\mu,\Sigma)\ \ \  and\ \ \  N(m,L)$$
but I do not know how to derive the Tr part
[image]

the $\operatorname{Tr}$ term is derived from 
$$\int e^{\{-1/2 (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\}}{(x-m)^TL^{-1}(x-m)}dx$$
what formulation dose it use?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(x-m)^TL^{-1}(x-m)$$ is a quadratic form, so it's scalar. We know that the trace of a scalar is the scalar itself, so $$(x-m)^TL^{-1}(x-m)=Tr((x-m)^TL^{-1}(x-m)).$$ Further, the trace of a product is invariant under cyclic permutations, so we can write $$Tr((x-m)^TL^{-1}(x-m))=Tr(L^{-1}(x-m)(x-m)^T).$$

Comment: thx，it's a clear explanation~